# Angular app on Apache server cannot find backend

Tags: angular, apache, apache2

I have a Angular 6 App which I start with `npm start` with proxy.conf.json configuration for backend configuration:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://123.123.1.23:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

The application is working properly but when I compile it using `ng build`(without -prod)  and deploy it on Apache server under /var/www/html I can open the web page but the communication with backend is not working probably because it can't be discovered.

I added this apache configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But still I can't login. Do you know am I missing something into my configuration?

Comment: As far as I know, proxy is only for development time. It was never meant for production.

Comment: ok, what configuration should I use?

Comment: IMO, best is to do http interceptor.

Comment: Can you show me example please?

Answer (score 0):

Example for Http Interceptor on one of my project:

Where apiUrl is where your API url is defined on environment.ts files.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = environment.apiUrl;

    req = req.clone({
      url: url + req.url,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
      })
    });

    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status === 401) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      }));
    }
  }
```

Module for registration:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class WebRequestInterceptorModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: WebRequestInterceptorModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('WebRequestInterceptorModule is already loaded. Import it in AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: WebRequestInterceptorModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInterceptorService, multi: true}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then register it on your app.module.ts
`WebRequestInterceptorModule.forRoot()`

Comment: Can you extend the answer a little bit where in which file and location I should add these configurations?